# AMDGPU driver DKMS module build fails in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: build, gpu, linux-device-driver, amd-gpu

I recently bought an AMD RX590 card (XFX 8GB Fatboy),
and tried to install on my Linux box. I downloaded the AMDGPU drivers from AMD's website,
and launched the installer `./amdgpu-install` on my machine.

I got the following error during installation:

```
Building for 5.6.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.6.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.6.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64 is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.6.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/make.log for more information.
```

Here is the output from make.log:

```
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/amd/amdgpu/smu_v11_0_i2c.c: In function 'smu_v11_0_i2c_transmit':
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/amd/amdgpu/smu_v11_0_i2c.c:237:6: error: 'drm_debug' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean '__drm_debug'?
  if (drm_debug & DRM_UT_DRIVER) {
      ^~~~~~~~~
      __drm_debug
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/amd/amdgpu/smu_v11_0_i2c.c:237:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/amd/amdgpu/smu_v11_0_i2c.c: In function 'smu_v11_0_i2c_receive':
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/amd/amdgpu/smu_v11_0_i2c.c:391:6: error: 'drm_debug' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean '__drm_debug'?
  if (drm_debug & DRM_UT_DRIVER) {
      ^~~~~~~~~
      __drm_debug
scripts/Makefile.build:267: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/amd/amdgpu/smu_v11_0_i2c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/amd/amdgpu/smu_v11_0_i2c.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
scripts/Makefile.build:505: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/amd/amdgpu' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build/amd/amdgpu] Error 2
Makefile:1708: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build' failed
make: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.53-1048554/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-16.2-liquorix-amd64'
```

Does anyone know how to make this work on Linux?
I tried to install amdgpu with the `--no-dkms` switch successfully, but the graphics card doesn't initialize with the AMD drivers, and shows up as `llvmpipe 9.0`. Any ideas how to make this works?